# adb not recognize the device

Tags: android, adb

While the phone is connected via USB to the laptop, I ran `adb devices` to check if adb communicates with the phone. However, no devic

```
PS C:\Users\Thinkpad\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools> .\adb.exe devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

PS C:\Users\Thinkpad\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools> .\adb.exe devices
List of devices attached
```

On the phone, I have set **Use USB to** to **Transfer files**.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have your turned on usb debugging??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on "USB Debugging" in the "Developer Options" area of Settings.

If you do not see "Developer Options", go into "About phone" in Settings and tap seven times on the "Build number", which will unlock "Developer Options".

Hope it helps.